# Java - Make an array list using while loop

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a JAVA beginner. How can I create multi dimension object/array list (something like bellow) using a while loop.

(I'm going to read a text file using JAVA Scanner and need to load data into a array list with following format)

```
Object[][] data = {

        {"Text1-Line1", "Text2-Line1","Text3-Line1","Text4-Line1","Text5-Line1"},
        {"Text1-Line2", "Text2-Line2","Text3-Line2","Text4-Line2","Text5-Line2"},
        {"Text1-Line3", "Text2-Line3","Text3-Line3","Text4-Line3","Text5-Line3"},

    };
```

Comment: I can't see a pattern to this data making it difficult to create it within a loop (the last 4 you could)

Comment: Try to solve it by yourself first. If you have a problem come here and we will help you. See you soon!

Comment: I changed the question. I can create a simple array using while loop, but don't know how to do it for array list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below

```
ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while(scanner.hasNext()){

   String[] text = scanner.nextLine().split(","); //assuming comma separated text in the line
   data.add(text);

}
```

printing the content

```
for (String[] text : data) {
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these high level steps:

1. Create a new instance of ArrayList
2. Open file and start reading
3. Read each row and split text into each cell.
4. Build an array of the data from the row
5. Add the row to ArrayList
6. Clean up any resources.

Comment: Much better than my answer while still avoiding giving code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a nested loops, one for each dimension (column) of your array.  Use the same loop you use to create a one-dimensional array, but put it inside one that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `while(in.hasNext()) { }` codeblock, and a for loop for both the x and y array bits.

Also, you should probably be using a String array and not an Object array. This should be enough to get you on the right path.